# why electron builder dont include files

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-builder, lokijs, electron-vue

I try to include lokiJS (locla json database) to my vue-electron app from [a vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/guide.html#table-of-contents)!.

src/db/db.js

```
const path = require('path')
import * as loki from 'lokijs';
const dbPath = path.resolve('src/db/db.json')
let db = new loki(dbPath);
export default db
```

src/main.js

```
import db from './db/db'
Vue.prototype.$db = db
```

src/components/component.vue

```
created() {
    const db = this.$db;
    db.loadDatabase({}, () => {
      let rooms = db.getCollection("rooms");
      this.rooms = rooms.find({ activ: true });
    });
  }
```

If I work in dev mode all works fine but when I build electron production app is import db from './db/db' not include. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you work in **dev** mode after build all the files kept inside the **resource** directory. like

```
                    app 
                     |-  dlls
                     |- app.exe
                     |- resources
                               |- app(folder)  all the JS files kept inside this.
```

But in case of **prod**

```
                   app 
                     |-  dlls
                     |- app.exe
                     |- resources
                               |- app.asar  all the JS files kept inside this zip.
```

so first check where to kep this and how you try to access this db file .

Hope it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your approach. I'm working on the Mac, I should have said that before, sorry, please. And Dev i mean if i want to look at app fast, i use npm run electron: serve. If you want to see the code on [a github](https://github.com/vincent41/ZimmerArchiv2019.git)